# SlidingMenu - RuntimeException

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am following [this tutorial][1], it has 2 parts. I followed part 1 and ran the app, it worked perfectly. Then I followed part 2 and I keep getting this `RuntimeException`

```
09-03 18:32:29.339: E/AndroidRuntime(21044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tvgenius/com.tvgenius.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
09-03 18:32:29.339: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
09-03 18:32:29.339: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
```

I followed the tutorial exactly. I don't know what I'm missing...

**Solution:** `minSdkVersion` for Fragments required is 12, mine was 11.

Comment: Can you please post the code giving this error?

Comment: See above, added MainActivity

Comment: Post the layout which contains the fragment.

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion ? It has to be 12 or you will need a support library!

Comment: See above, added `slidingmenu.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use fragments you need minimum sdk version to be 12 or you have to download a [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

Just right click on your **project->android tools -> add support library...**

Instead of:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

you have to use:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: The MainActivity is added to the Manifest. Which other one?

Comment: That's it :) the `minSdkVersion` was the problem. Changed to 12 and it worked :)

Comment: better use support library so you can lower your minSdk back.

Comment: I went to Project > here there is no Android Tools. I went to Window > Android SDK Manager > I installed Extras > "Android Support Library". How do I add it to my project?

Comment: After the click you have to accept the License and then it is done automatically, now you have to change your imports.  
Instead of: `import android.app.Fragment;` you have to use: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`  
Also if I gave you the solution to your problem you should accept my answer.